# create-guten-block in wordpress theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, templates, visual-editor, block-editor

I'm working on a wordpress theme and want to replace my shortcodes with gutenberg blocks. I'm new to working with blocks but having looked into it a bit I've decided to try and use [create-guten-block](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block) as that seemed like a good starting point.

The tutorial on github mentions that you should install the blocks to the plugins directory, whereas ideally I want them to be built in to my theme. Is it possible to do it this way or is it necessary to have them in a plugin?

Comment: Ideally themes only touch styling of the content and plugins modify or create content. So I guess blocks should belong to plugins. But sure, you can create blocks within a theme. In the end you just need to enqueue a script which then registers the block.

Answer (score 1):

Creator of create-guten-block here. You should be building Gutenberg blocks via companion plugins. Keep your theme for styles only :) That's the best practice for now.

Comment: I know why it's considered best practice but if you wanted to do it anyway, how would you do it?